# Flutter: _InternalLinkedHashMap has no instance > method 'cast'

Tags: dart, flutter

Sthg makes me crazy, I try to show json products in cards and it doesn't work. Here is what I tried so far:

**Product class :**

```
class Product {
   final String id;

   Product({this.id});

   factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
       return new Product(
          id: json['id'] as String
       );
  }
 }
```

**JSON:**

```
Future loadProducts() async {
   final response = await http.get('https://api.stripe.com/v1/products');
   return response.body;
}
```

The json has the following structure (data contains a list of products):

[image]

**Widget:**

```
Widget get _homeView {
  return new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
       new FutureBuilder(
             future: loadProducts(),
             builder: (context, snapshot) {

                  List<Product> products = parseJson(snapshot.data.toString());
                  return !products.isEmpty 
                     ? new ProductsList(product: products) 
                     : new CircularProgressIndicator();
             }
       ),
       ...
     ]
  );
}

List<Product> parseJson(String response) {
    final parsed = json.decode(response.toString()).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<Product>((json) => new Product.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

**ProductsList class:**

```
class ProductsList extends StatelessWidget {
    final List<Product> product;
    ProductsList({Key key, this.product}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: product == null ? 0 : product.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
             return new Card(
                child: new Container(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(product[index].id),
                  ],
                )
             );
          }
        );
      }
   }
```

Error :

> Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap' has no instance
>   method 'cast' with matching arguments.

**Edit 1 :**

I tried :
[image]
Error :
[image]

Comment: The method exists though https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Map/cast.html What Dart version are you using?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Just for reference, [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51) is quite handy for explaining parsing JSON in Flutter and I find myself going back to it every now and then.

Comment: I'm using Dart2 @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 0):

This is my usual method for parsing a json list of objects (bit simpler but it works):

```
List<Product> parseJson(String response) {
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    List jsonParsed = json.decode(response.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonParsed.length; i++) {
      products.add(new Product.fromJson(jsonParsed[i]));
    }
    return products;
}
```